# SendGrid not sending emails Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I am trying to send mails with SendGrid from my Rails app (using Hartl's tutorial). It didn't work by simply using the addon at Heroku because it needed my credit card. Then I signed up on SendGrid and used my credentials as above, but still no mail. Here above is my production.rb file. Some help, please?

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = '<https://nameless-sierra-13544>.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['myusername'],
    :password       => ENV['mypass#'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Merci,

Comment: Does your `host` value literally contain `<` and `>`? And why is `:domain` set to `'heroku.com'`? Shouldn't that be your app's full domain?

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out?

Comment: @Rockwell Rice, actually no, I followed your suggestion but it didn't work, maybe the problem is somewhere else in the code and I can't figgure it out.

Comment: You do have all the ENV variables set in heroku, correct?

Comment: I certainly did not in the beginning, for development it works now. I encrypted my gmail credentials (using: rails credentials:edit) and the variables are properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with the comment above, I believe your values are just a little off.  I also believe you need to have a `from` address set.  This is a copy of what I use in production, with your values put in, and it works so hopefully this helps.  I do believe that missing a valid `from` address and the characters in your domain value are why this is not working.  Of course, also make sure you have the `ENV` variables set on heroku.

production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'https://nameless-sierra-13544.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :from                 => 'your_email_here@email.com',
    :user_name            => ENV['myusername'],
    :password             => ENV['mypass#'],
    :domain               => 'https://nameless-sierra-13544.herokuapp.com',
    :address              => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port                 => 587,
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't host and domain be the same?

Comment: Ya you are 100% correct.  I forgot to update that when putting the code in.